# How to map the mutiple uploaded files to Java Controller?

Tags: javascript, java

Following is my Javascript Code to create and send the POST request. If you see, since I want to upload multiple files. I have used nodeDoc[] to append every file.

```
var file = document.getElementById("nodeDoc");
var formData = new FormData();
for(var i=0;i<file.files.length;i++)
    formData.append("nodeDoc[]", file.files[i]);
formData.append('userId', readCookie('userId'));
formData.append('passwd', readCookie('passwd'));
formData.append('treeType', selectedTreeType);
formData.append('displayName', document.getElementById('displayName').value);
formData.append('nodeType', document.getElementById('nodeType').value);  
formData.append('attrList', constructAttrList());
client.open("post", serverUrl + "node/addNode", true);
client.send(formData);
console.log("/node/addNode API called with file");
document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "block";
```

Following is the Java controller code. Am i going wrong in receiving it as MultipartFile[] as given below?  I could not upload even a single file now.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "node/addNode", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public @ResponseBody String addNodeAndDocNew(@RequestParam TreeType treeType, @RequestParam(required = false) ObjectId parentNodeId, @RequestParam NodeType nodeType,
        @RequestParam String displayName, @RequestParam String attrList, @RequestParam(value = "nodeDoc", required = true) MultipartFile[] files,
        @RequestParam String userId, @RequestParam String passwd) {
    log.info("==== in addNodeAndDoc() ====");
    return service.addNodeAndDocNew(treeType, parentNodeId, nodeType, displayName, attrList, files, userId, passwd);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Its unclear what your problem is

Comment: @ShervinAsgari If I try to print the files variable, It's showing  [Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;@5adb75da and hence I could not use it further.

Comment: @KavithaMadhavaraj its an object.. If you print the object you will get output like this only.. Check the files is not null and its size

Comment: @AnoopLL I did try, if (files == null || files.length < 1) evaluates to true always.

Comment: @KavithaMadhavaraj loop means loop in the javascript?

Comment: @KavithaMadhavaraj did you set content-type to multipart/form-data??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102223/discussion-between-kavitha-madhavaraj-and-anoop-ll).